# How to make a Thumbnails Mosaic

Tags: categories, templates, post-thumbnails

I would like to make a mosaic with all the post thumbnails of a category and use it as the heading image on the category page. How do I go about achieving this? Where do I start?

Any suggestion about how to approach the task will be appreciated!

Comment: You're maybe searching for something like [Masonry for jQuery](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html)?

Comment: Well Masonry it's absolutely a great thing that I didn't know until now but my goal is something simpler. I'm talking about grabbing only the images crop'em or resize'em in little tiles and putting them one close to the other in three or four rows with a "category title" over this composition... and then a loop of post of that category.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) to set a new size for those cat images: `add_image_size( 'mosaic', $your_width, $your_height, true );`. The rest depends on your category image (this isn't default, but done by some plugin or something else).